# Print Totals (all records on table) on page footer section

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, report

i have crystal reports for visual studio 2008, i have some problems trying to print the overall total under page footer,
i used running totals but it shows only the total for page one and the accumulated for page two, but i want to show the grand total from the first page to the last page.

ex. i have a total for page one that is 1.58
for the second page i have a total for 2.58
i want to print 2.58 (grand total) from first page to last page under page footer section.

Hope someone can help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Place the total in Report Footer instead of page footer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean

A) Total appears in the page footer

page 1 total 10

page 2 total 12
       gand Total 22

page 3 total 11
       grand total 33

Or do you want it like this  
B) In the page footer 
page 1 total 10 
page 2 total 12 
page 3 total 11 
Grand total 33

If you pick A or B I can get a better idea of what you want and be able to thelp

Answer (score 0):

Try using formula field to sum the field of your data and show it in the page footer